# How to hide edit_bar when displaying a form with wrap_form?

Tags: plone

I have a z3c.form based form.

When I display it I get the edit_bar (Contents / View / Rule /Sharing).

How do I hide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put self.request.set('disable_border',1) in the form's init or update method

Please see david glick's comment

Answer (score 1):

This was the trick used before:

http://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/template_basics.html#edit-frame

But you need to have your own master template for the form set first.

Comment: Even if you don't have a custom template you can put self.request.set('disable_border',1) in the form's __init__ or update method.

Comment: @david.. can you please make this an answer so i can check it as the right answer?